# сложение времени за два дня итого в новую

Tags: битрикс

Есть две даты:

```
Первая - человек пришел на работу 16:15 19 Августа

Вторая - человек ушел с работы 08:45 20 Августа
```

Как правильно написать чтобы вывело в таблицу что он отработал 16:30 часов?

```js
<tr class='tr_1'>
    <td>Число</td>
    <td>Приход</td>
    <td>Уход</td>
    <td>Обед</td>
    <td>Итого</td>
</tr> 
<?
do {
include ('blocks/time.php');
printf (" <tr class='tr_1'> <td>%s %s</td> <td>%s : %s</td> <td>%s : %s</td> <td>%s мин.</td> <td>%s </td> </tr>"
, $myrow['day'], $myrow2['month2'], $myrow['hours'], $myrow['minutes'], $myrow['hours2'], $myrow['minutes2'], $myrow['obed'], $myrow['final']);
}
```

Comment: Перевести все даты в секунды и вычесть одно из другого, потом остаток переделать в удобный для вывода формат.

Comment: а причем тут Битрикс?